# How to get cursor position in electron

Tags: electron

we can find the mouse position using the below snippet

```
electron.app.on('ready', ()=> {
        // get the mouse position
        let mousePos = electron.screen.getCursorScreenPoint();
        console.log(mousePos);
});
```

I there any way to get the cursor position(not mouse position) in electron js ?

Comment: what is the difference between cursor position and mouse position?

Comment: Cursor is showing only in edit text input fields

Answer (score -2):

```
var oTextarea = document.getElementById("textarea");  
var start = oTextarea.selectionStart;  
var end = oTextarea.selectionEnd;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.